# multipart/form-data not setting in MultipartEncoder (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to upload a file to a server and it only accepts the file in multipart/form-data format so when i try to send it by encoding like:

```
        m = MultipartEncoder(
            fields={'document': json.dumps(metadata),
                    'files': (file_name, open(file_path,'rb'),'multipart/form-data')}
            )
        headers = {'content-type': m.content_type}
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=m)
```

It still shows the error:

> '{"success":false,"errorMsg":"Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"}'

How do i resolve this when i have explicitly set the content-type to multipart/form-data?